# Replace string in dataframe with result from function

Tags: python, function, pyspark, pattern-matching

I have multiple text files with sql code I've converted into dataframes to modify and use to create tables. To do so, I need to fuzzy match the `database.tablenames` in the sql code to the closest match to `database.tablenames` in my platform.

This regex isolates instances of database.tablename in the example dataframe below:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([
('REPLACE VIEW COMPANY_TP_US.BEST_VR_TP AS',),
('SELECT CAR.PART_ID,',),
('CAR.TYPE_CD,',),
('FROM COMPANY_TP_US.TRANSMIT_PART CAR',),
('WHERE YR_MO = (',),
('SELECT MAX(YR_MO)',),
('FROM COMPANY_BR.VII_ID_NO_42_TP);',)],
 ["syntax"])

df_test = df.withColumn('regex2', when(col('syntax').rlike('COMPANY.'), regexp_replace(df.syntax, '\w+\.(.*)', 'placeholder'))\
                       .otherwise(col('syntax')))
```

I'd like to replace the word 'placeholder' with the closest fuzzy match from a list of ~1K different database.tablenames I've created as a separate dataframe. My end goal is to create new tables by running the syntax above with the replaced placeholder in pyspark.sql.

With a similar type of problem, I've previously converted the sql code into a string, identified the `placeholder` and then used difflib's get_close_matches function to replace the placeholder. However, these new `dataframes` have multiple subqueries with different `database.tablenames` that I thought might be easier to use a `dataframe` to replace the placeholders before converting them into string format. The example above is the simplest example. I've used the function below to find fuzzy matches in the past.

```
#best match
  str = f'{placeholder}'
  best_tbl_match = get_close_matches(str, db_tbl_patterns, n=1)
```

example matching `database.tablenames` in additional database:

```
'company.change_best_vr_tp_23', 
'company.ir_wv_ei_transmit_part_23', 
'company.eng_vii_id_no_42_tp_23', 
'company.eng_v2_id_no_53_tp_23', 
'company.change_best_vr_increasing_tp_23'
```

What would be the best way to go about this problem? There's likely better ways to address this question than the method I'm using. Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a user defined function that will replace the `get_close_matches` to each of your row.

edit: lets try to create a separate column containing the matched 'COMPANY.' string, and then use the user defined function to replace it with the closest match based on the list of `database.tablenames`.

edit2: now lets use `regexp_extract` for full matched string and `udf` to replace only the database table name with its closest match

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, col, when, regexp_extract, lit
from difflib import get_close_matches

def fuzzy_replace(match_string, candidates_list):
    best_match = get_close_matches(match_string, candidates_list, n=1)
    return best_match[0] if best_match else match_string

fuzzy_replace_udf = udf(fuzzy_replace)

db_tbl_patterns_list = [row['db_table'] for row in db_tbl_patterns_df.collect()]
db_tbl_patterns_list = [x.upper() for x in db_tbl_patterns_list]  # Convert to uppercase if needed

df_test = df.withColumn('matched', when(col('syntax').rlike('COMPANY.'), regexp_extract(df.syntax, '((?i)COMPANY\..*)', 1))\
                       .otherwise('skip'))

def replace_with_fuzzy(matched, syntax):
    if matched != 'skip':
        closest_match = fuzzy_replace(matched, db_tbl_patterns_list)
        return syntax.replace(matched, closest_match)
    else:
        return syntax

replace_with_fuzzy_udf = udf(replace_with_fuzzy)

df_result = df_test.withColumn('syntax', replace_with_fuzzy_udf(col('matched'), col('syntax'))).drop('matched')

df_result.show(truncate=False)
```

Comment: Thank you! This is very close to the result I'm trying to reach. Ultimately I'm trying to create a dataframe with all of the sql syntax in the example dataframe, but with whatever word that I indicated as 'placeholder' replaced with the best match from db_tbl_patterns. I modified the code for df_test above in my question to show what the end df would look like, just with 'placeholder' replaced. So index 1 would ideally become 'REPLACE VIEW company.change_best_vr_tp_23' and index 4 would become 'FROM company.ir_wv_ei_transmit_part_23'.

Comment: In the real data, there are multiple similar tables so I needed to use the closest match. Thank you!

Comment: It's not working yet because the 'placeholder' is hardcoded in df_test so df_result is not able to fuzzy_match. Ideally, the 'placeholder' word in regexp_replace would be replaced with the function to create the word that matches best (i.e. fuzzy_replace_udf(col('syntax'), udf(lambda: db_tbl_patterns_list)())), but that results in a 'column is not iterable' error message.

Comment: I see, I updated again :)

Comment: Thank you! I think we're so close. I modified the .otherwise(None) to .otherwise(lit('skip')) to avoid the 'unable to iterate over nonetype' error. The when clause below is then 'when(col('matched')!= 'skip'. The fuzzy matching function works when I convert the db_tbl_patterns_list to capital case, but the udf portion doesn't seem to be working as df_result includes the original db.tbl name. Also, I'll have to find a way to include the rest of the text besides the db.tbl name too since col('matched') currently strips out just the db.tbl name. Thank you!

Comment: New update :)))

Comment: Everything works well except for the fuzzy matching portion. Are you able to see matches on your end? Thanks again!